# Functions for which $\mathcal{F}g = f \ast f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose one is given $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, my question is whether or not there exists a $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f \ast f = \mathcal{F}g$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.

Conversely, suppose one is given a $g \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, then does there exist an $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathcal{F}g = f \ast f$?

Formally, the answer for the first question should be $g := \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f \ast f)$. But of course all I know is that $f \ast f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Is $*$ referring to multiplication or convolution? In either case, you'll want to recall how convolutions and multiplication interact under Fourier transforms.

Comment: The $\ast$ refers to convolution. I know that $\mathcal{F}(f \ast g) = (\mathcal{F}f)(\mathcal{F}g)$, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that the convolution theorem applies to both directions of Fourier transformation (i.e. both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$). To put it another way: it's also the case that $(f\,*\,g)(\omega)=\mathcal{F(f\cdot g)}(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed that, $g$ should be, $(f\ast f)^{\vee}.$ Next, observe that, $g= f^{\vee}\cdot f^{\vee}= (f^{\vee})^{2}.$ Since $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R),$ we have $f^{\vee}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ (by Planchrel) and  therefore $(f^{\vee})^{2}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R);$ and so $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R).$

On the other hand,  Given $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ to find $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ so that $f\ast f= \hat{g}.$

Observer that, $(f^{\vee})^{2}= g,$ then $f^{\vee} =(g)^{\frac{1}{2}};$ (Why ?, this step may not be true) and since, $g\in L^{1},$ we have $f^{\vee}\in L^{2},$ therefore by Planchrel, $f\in L^{2}.$

Comment: I'm not completely sure we can use the convolution identity for Fourier Transforms here as $f\in L^2$ but it is not necessarily the case that $f \in L^1$.

Comment: @BaronMingus; For $f, g \in L^{2}(\mathbb R^{n}),$ it is true that, $(\hat{f} \hat{g})^{\vee}= f\ast g.$

Comment: @Inquistive; Is this true even when $ f*g $ is not in $ L^2 $?

Comment: @BaronMingus If $f,g \in L^2$, then $f \ast g \in L^2$ by Young's inequality.

Comment: @saz; By Young's inequality, $L^{2}\ast L^{2}\subset L^{\infty}.$ (Please note that, one can find $f, g \in L^{2}$ but $f\ast g \notin L^{2})$

Comment: @BaronMingus; Yes, it is true. (Note that, $f, g \in L^{2}$, so $\hat{f}, \hat{g}\in L^{2}$ and therefor $\hat{f}\hat{g} \in L^{1}$ and therefore, $(\hat{f}\hat{g})^{\vee}$ make sense, and it is in $L^{\infty}$)

Comment: @saz Young's inequality states that for $ f \in L^p,\,\, g\in L^q, $ then the inequality $||f*g||_{L^r} \leq ||f||_{L^p}||g||_{L^q} $ holds for $\frac {1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = \frac {1}{r} +1 $, $1 \leq p, q, r \leq \infty. $ In particular, for $ p=q=2, $ all we can say is that the $L^{\infty} $ norm of the convolution is bounded. $ L^2 $ is not closed under convolution. I'm not completely sure if this has any bearing on the problem but I feel it should - can you legitimately take the Fourier Transform of a non $ L^2 $ function?

Comment: @Inquisitive thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: @Inquisitive Ah, okay, I'm sorry.